Good way to stabilise hand landmarks with help of two cameras?
I want to be able to stabilize a set of landmarks with the help of two cameras, right now im using a dual camera setup and cvzone.HandTrackingModule for both cameras. So the output is two landmarklist for the joints where [x,y,z] is stored, after that we use triangulation to be able to caluclate a depth(z) that is an estimate. The problem arise that when I turn the hand flat for one of the cameras the landmarks gets displaced cause it can't see the finger so the landmark list becomes incorrect. Is there a way to kinda merge the two landmarklist from both cameras to give an output of a more stable landmarklist that don't flip out when the hand is in a bad postion. The cameras are mounted parallel and are of the same type and parameters.
I have no real idea how this is done so right now I use only one cameras landmarks with the calcuated depth from both cameras but that is not optimal.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
